# Reduce an array of objects based on object field

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a `Country` object and a `City` object

```
struct Country: {
  let name: String
  let countryCode: String
  let cities: [City]
  let population: Int

  init(name: String, countryCode: String, cities: [City], population: Int) { 
    self.name = name 
    self.countryCode = countryCode
    self.cities = cities
    self.population = population
  }
}

struct City {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double
  let countryCode: String
  let population: Int
}
```

Incoming `JSON` data looks like this which decodes into `[City]` array

```
{
   "cities":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Paris",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"FR",
         "population":0
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Nice",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"FR",
         "population":0
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Berlin",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"DE",
         "population":0
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"Munich",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"DE",
         "population":0
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"Amsterdam",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"NL",
         "population":0
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "name":"Leiden",
         "latitude":0,
         "logitude":0,
         "country_code":"NL",
         "population":0
      }
   ]
}
```

How would I create `[Country]` array from `[City]` array efficiently? I've tried to use `reduce:into:` but not sure that's what I have to use.

I know I could go with an empty array and add/create Countries one by one then search if there is one already and add City to it. That creates awful looking code as for me. I feel like there is an elegant solution to this problem using map or reduce functions.

`reduce:into:` code I've tried so far

```
func transformArrayOf(_ cities: [City]) -> [Country] {

  let empty: [Country] = []
        
  return cities.reduce(into: empty) { countries, city in
          
    let existing = countries.filter { $0.countryCode == city.countryCode }.first
    countries[existing].cities.append(city)
  }
}
```

EDIT:

The function only gets `[City]` array. So countries must be created only from that.

`Dictionary(grouping:by:)` with `map(_:)` works perfectly! Two lines instead on nested `for` loops and `if` statements :)

And `Country` name can be parsed from a country code

Comment: The `JSON` is an implementation detail. If you want us to be able to run these snippets and be able to help better, I suggest you replace the `JSON` text with a array literal containing hard-coded `City` struct instances. That way we don't have to figure out the json decoding logic just to run this code

Comment: How are your countries created? They contain data that isn't derived from the cities (e.g. `name`, `countryName` (how are those different?), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`** and **`map(_:)`** combined to get the expected result.

```
let countries = Dictionary(grouping: cities, by: { $0.countryCode }).map { (countryCode, cities) -> Country in
    return Country(name: "", countryCode: countryCode, countryName: "", cities: cities, population: cities.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.population })
}
```

Since the values for `name` and `countryName` are unknown, I've used empty `String` (`""`) for both.

Comment: Instantiating Country with empty values really doesn't add any value so this answer looks like a duplicate to me. And your assumption that all people live in cities is not correct.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't think this is a duplicate. And about the empty Strings, I've already mentioned that they are unknown and OP can fill in himself.

Comment: No, the properties are `let` declared :) It would be better to find out from OP where the data for the countries is supposed to come from IMO

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) is for:

```
let citiesByCountryCode = Dictionary(grouping: cities, by: \.countryCode)
```

But you'll need separate logic to create the countries, because they contain data that isn't derived from the cities like `name`, `countryName` (how are those different?), etc.